# How to update the value of the item in an array if it exists in json using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have a Json file which I want to update using `jq`. I am working on Ubuntu with `jq-1.6`

```
test_data.json
```

```
{
    "A": "12",
    "B": "34",
    "C": [
        ["X", "test1"],
        ["Y", "test2"],
        ["Z", "test3"]
    ]
}
```

Now I want to update array `C` with new key:value pair. But, if the any of the key already exists then it's value should be updated.

```
update='[
    ["Z", "test4"],
    ["D", "test5"],
    ["E", "test6"]
    ]'
```

In this case the item `Z` already exists in `test_data.json` but `update` has new value for the item.

Expected output:

```
{
    "A": "12",
    "B": "34",
    "C": [
        ["X", "test1"],
        ["Y", "test2"],
        ["Z", "test4"],
        ["D", "test5"],
        ["E", "test6"]
    ]
}
```

So far, I could do

```
cat test_data.json | jq --argjson val "${update}" '.C += $val')
```

But this is not updating value for item `Z`, instead adding new entry.

Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Z` is not a key, it's just the first (regular) item of an array. Keys are a concept of objects like `{"Z": "test4"}`. (Note the curly braces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.C` array and the `$update` array both have arrays as items. You need to consider their first item to be a unique key, so that clashes can lead to overwrites. One way could be turning them into an `INDEX` object first, then `add` up those, and retrieve their items back into an array:

```bash
jq --argjson val "$update" '.C |= [[., $val | INDEX(.[0])] | add[]]' test_data.json
```

```json
{
  "A": "12",
  "B": "34",
  "C": [
    [
      "X",
      "test1"
    ],
    [
      "Y",
      "test2"
    ],
    [
      "Z",
      "test4"
    ],
    [
      "D",
      "test5"
    ],
    [
      "E",
      "test6"
    ]
  ]
}
```